# Accessing a class array element with . in C++ or mistake in Stroustrup book

Tags: c++

In the book Programming Principles and Practice with C++ by B. Stroustrup I have come across a piece of code where the argument is the array of a basic version of the vector class. The class is defined as

```
class vector {
    int sz;
    double * elem;
public:
    vector(const vector &);
    //...
};
//...
vector::vector(const vector &arg)
     :sz{arg.sz},elem{new double[arg.sz]}
{
     copy(arg.elem,arg.elem.sz,elem);
}
```

My questions: is 'arg.elem.sz' a valid expression? If yes, What is this accessing?

(By the way, I have tried to write a simple piece of code to try this, but I get an error. As arg.elem is a pointer, it expects me to do something more like 'arg.elem->')

Thanks!

EDIT/UPDATE: the syntax seems to be correct. Looking at the definition of copy, the argument is an 'iterator'. I suspect there must be something about converting the argument to an iterator type, then getting the sz-th pointed element becomes accessing the element of the iterator? Clarifications welcomed :)

Comment: That looks like it should be `arg.elem+sz` instead.

Comment: Hm, looks like it is mentioned in errata [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2errata.html), but the change is to this expression, not from it. What edition are you using?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. It is the the 4th printing, page 635 (so you have sent me to the correct errata :) ). However in the errata correction the syntax remains :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a typo, the `arg.elem.sz` is not a valid expression because the `arg.elem` is a `double*` which has no member to access (nor with the `->` opertor). It should be `arg.elem + arg.sz` there because this is how the [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) works.

In your update you asked about the *iterator* and the [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) algorithm. The `std::copy` is a [function template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template) which accepts any type as input and as output iterators if they satisfy the requirements of an [input iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator) and of an [output iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/OutputIterator). A pointer to an array element satisfies the mentioned requirements, so the `arg.elem` as being an `double*` can be used as an iterator.

If we change the questioned line of code to the following, it will make sense:

```
copy(arg.elem, arg.elem + arg.sz, elem);
```

The code above will copy the content of array between `arg.elem` and `arg.elem + arg.sz` to the array pointed by `elem`.

Comment: isn't `sz` a member or `arg` as well? meaning it should be `copy(arg.elem, arg.elem + arg.sz, elem)`

Answer (score 0):

Trying to compile that (used myvector instead of vector to prevent clashes with the standard vector) using gcc one gets:

```
c++ -std=c++11 -o a a.cpp
a.cpp: In copy constructor ‘myvector::myvector(const myvector&)’:
a.cpp:24:26: error: request for member ‘sz’ in ‘arg.myvector::elem’, which is 
of non-class type ‘double* const’
  copy(arg.elem, arg.elem.sz, elem);
                      ^
```

I suspect the errata needs fixing to +sz instead